# How to use custom modules on heroku python app

Tags: python, heroku, module

I am trying to deploy a Python app on heroku, which has a structure like this

```
main.py
module1.py
folder
|--__init__.py
|--module2.py
```

The problem is that running on heroku, it doesn't find the module inside folder.

I tried literally everything inside the `__init__.py` and `main.py`, and now my `__init__.py` looks like this

```
#__init__
from .module2 import y
```

and the `main.py`

```
#main
from module1 import x
from folder import y
```

but I get this error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'y'

I already tried using `from folder import *` and defining `__all__` inside every module in the folder, but nothing changes

The strange part is that nearly everything of what I tried worked in local using pycharm

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py`? Are you installing your application as a module in your environment, e.g. via something like `pip install -e .`?